# Can you auto-invite new members of a distribution list to a meeting?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-2013

At the beginning of the year the members of the "All Employees" distribution list is invited to the quarterly company meetings.  The problem is that when a new employee is hired on and their mailbox is created and added to the "All Employees" distribution list they arn't automatically invited to the meetings.  Is there a way to set this up?  Or I suppose their might be a way to write a PowerShell script to create the new mailbox and invite them to the meetings at the same time. But that wouldn't be quite as nice of a solution.

Edit: If it helps at all we are using Microsoft's hosted Office365 Exchange

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't know but I'll do some research on it if nobody else knows.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in to Exchange to do this. Yes, this could be scripted with EWS and PowerShell, but a quick Google did not yield any completed solutions to this problem.